# Adding Full Text Catalog to VS2013 causes build errors in SQL database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I want to use my DB project to contain the definition of my full text catalog and its indexes. I've added the catalog to my SQL server instance and created an index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [FTSCatalog]
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
AS DEFAULT
AUTHORIZATION [username_UAT];
```

with the index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[tablename]
([ColumnName] LANGUAGE 1033)
KEY INDEX [PK_tablename]
ON [FTSCatalog];
```

However, the SQL DB project gives an error on the definition of FTSCatalog

```
Error   2   SQL71501: Full-text Catalog: [FTSCatalog] has an unresolved reference to object [username_UAT]
```

Using the SQL database schema compare tool to synchronise the user generates a user file that contains this:

```
CREATE USER [username_UAT] FOR LOGIN [username_UAT];
```

The error now moves to this file, but it contains an oddly looking circular reference. The error is now on the second occurrence of username_UAT:

```
Error   2   SQL71501: User: [username_UAT] has an unresolved reference to Login [username_UAT]
```

In the schema compare options object types I have Users, Full-Text Catalogs and Full-Text indexes checked. There is no option to synchronise logins.

How do I get the definition of my full text catalog into my SQL DB project?

Answer (score 1):

This stackoverflow question gave me the answer:

[How to create a user for a login in 2013 SQL Server Database Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848722/how-to-create-a-user-for-a-login-in-2013-sql-server-database-project)

I had to check the "logins" checkbox on the Non-Application scoped section of the compare options object types.